# What is Inner Like join?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In the Spark source code for join strategies, code comments mention for Broadcast hash join (BHJ):

> BHJ is not supported for full outer join. For right outer join, we
>   only can broadcast the left side. For left outer, left semi, left anti
>   and the internal join type ExistenceJoin, we only can broadcast the
>   right side. For inner like join, we can broadcast both sides.
>   Normally, BHJ can perform faster than the other join algorithms when
>   the broadcast side is small. However, broadcasting tables is a
>   network-intensive operation. It could cause OOM or perform worse than
>   the other join algorithms, especially when the build/broadcast side is
>   big.

Could you please explain what does the code comments mean by

> "inner-like join"

[code link](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala)

Comment: I read the phrase as: "For a join like an inner join...", though a normal `inner join` is the only "like an inner join" I can think of.

Comment: @TravisHegner: thanks, looks like it includes inner and cross join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to [a doc for the dataset join operators](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-joins.html) innerlike is used for INNER and CROSS joins.

> You can also find that Spark SQL uses the following two families of
>   joins:
>
> - InnerLike with Inner and Cross
> - LeftExistence with LeftSemi, LeftAnti and ExistenceJoin

Answer (score 1):

Finally found in the code: [joinTypes.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/joinTypes.scala)

InnerLike includes: Inner and Cross joins.

```
sealed abstract class InnerLike extends JoinType {
  def explicitCartesian: Boolean
}

case object Inner extends InnerLike {
  override def explicitCartesian: Boolean = false
  override def sql: String = "INNER"
}

case object Cross extends InnerLike {
  override def explicitCartesian: Boolean = true
  override def sql: String = "CROSS"
}
```